# Matlab on the command line error in Lion

Tags: time-machine, command-line

I constantly get this warning in Matlab, which I run on the command line:

> This process is attempting to exclude an item from Time Machine by path without administrator privileges. This is not supported.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: What part of your code is trying to alter Time Machine information?

Comment: no part at all... Matlab just starts spitting out this warning, even with me doing nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Matlab as administrative user once so it can do the exclusion.

Answer (score 2):

It is reported [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/matlabcentral/answers/18762-annoying-matlab-start-up-warnings-on-mac-matlab_maci64-attempting-to-exclude-an-item-from), they claimed that the issue is for all version of Matlab on Mac OS X Lion. So I guess you could simply use ***sudo*** to get this problem done. And wait with more patient for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo matlab` once worked for me.  This assumes that `/Applications/MATLAB_R20???.app/bin` has been added to `PATH`.